# while loop in sql I iterate not id but varchar values one by one from other table

Tags: sql-server, loops, while-loop

I want to use while loop and iterate values one by one like "server1name", "server2name", "server3name" from some other table, below code related to make sql job from sp this is to create it at a time on 4 diff environments and I want to use while loop in below sp

```
--use msdb;
--IF  EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = N'TORODO1')
--EXEC sp_delete_job @job_name = N'TORODO1' , @delete_unused_schedule=1
--DROP PROCEDURE dbo.JobCreation
--sp_helptext 'dbo.JobCreation';
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.JobCreation
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @JobName VARCHAR(30)= 'TORODO1';

EXEC    msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name= @jobName, 
        @enabled=0,                                             
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'CORP\StaSQLExec';

EXEC    msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_name= @jobName, @step_name=N'DUMMY_1', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=3, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
        --@database_name=N'NPKSTADAT11',  
        @database_name=@server1name, --server2name, server3name-- here want to apply while loop
        @command=N'/SQL "\Dummy" /SERVER NPKSTADAT11 /CONFIGFILE "E:\SSIS_Package_Repository\Dummy\PackageDependencies_20120801\Dummy.dtsconfig" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E', 
        @flags=0;

EXEC    msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_name=@jobName, @step_name=N'DUMMY_2', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=3, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
        --@database_name=N'NPKSTADAT11',  
        @database_name=N'master',
        @command=N'/SQL "\Dummy" /SERVER NPKSTADAT11 /CONFIGFILE "E:\SSIS_Package_Repository\Dummy\PackageDependencies_20120801\Dummy.dtsconfig" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E',
        @flags=0;

EXEC    msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_name=@jobName, @name=N'Dummy_schedule_2', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=8, 
        @freq_interval=63, 
        @freq_subday_type=1, 
        @freq_subday_interval=0, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
        @active_start_date=20120831, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=0, 
        @active_end_time=235959 
        --@schedule_uid=N'08468e56-ffbc-45b0-a3ac-a812bcf8401c'

EXEC    msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_name=@jobName, @name=N'DUMMY_step_1_schedule', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=4, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=1, 
        @freq_subday_interval=0, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=0, 
        @active_start_date=20120831, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=230000, 
        @active_end_time=235959 
        --@schedule_uid=N'ef28ae48-cf83-46c7-b83e-973df6adc62d'
EXEC    msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_name=@jobName, @server_name = N'(local)'
    END 

        Go
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into [Cursors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29) to drive your while loop.  Something like

```
declare myCursor cursor for
  select servername from ServerTable

open myCursor
fetch next from myCursor into @serverName

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
   ... do the work ...
   fetch next from myCursor into @serverName
end

close myCursor
deallocate myCursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use while loop.

```
SELECT  Servername ,
    0 AS Status 
 INTO    #temp1
 FROM    ServerTable
 DECLARE @variable VARCHAR(50)

WHILE EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1
                    NULL
           FROM     #temp1 AS T
           WHERE    T.Status = 0 ) 

BEGIN

    UPDATE TOP ( 1 )
            #temp1
    SET     Status = 1
    WHERE   #temp1.Status = 0

    SELECT TOP 1
            @variable = Servername
    FROM    #temp1 AS T
    WHERE   T.Status = 0

...Do your work...

    DELETE  FROM #temp1
    WHERE   #temp1.Status = 1


END
```

`